# Mongoose error: Schema hasn't been registered for model when populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to join two collections and being able to get the combined data. To do so using Mongoose, i am supposed to use the populate syntax to achieve that. I am receiving error that the Schema Schema hasn't been registered for 'User_Fb'. From my code, I have exported the models and required in my server.js but the error is still appearing. What have I done wrong?

feed_post.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var conn_new_app     = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/new_app');
var User_fb = require('../models/fb_db.model');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var feed_postSchema = new Schema({
    user_id:  { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User_Fb' },
    content: String,
    location: String,
    image: [{ type : String }]
});

var Feed_Post = conn_new_app.model('Feed_Post', feed_postSchema);

module.exports = Feed_Post;
```

fb_db.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var conn_new_app     = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/new_app');
var Feed_Post = require('../models/feed_post.model');

var user_fb = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    location: String,
    fb_id: Number
});

var User_Fb = conn_new_app.model('User_Fb', user_fb);

module.exports = User_Fb;
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),

mongoose = require('mongoose'),
User = require('./app/models/user.model'),
Post = require('./app/models/post.model'),
Maptest = require('./app/models/maptest.model'),
Feed_Post = require('./app/models/feed_post.model'),
User_Fb = require('./app/models/fb_db.model'),

app = express();

app.get('/testget', function(req,res){
    Feed_Post.findOne().populate('user_id').exec(function(err, c) {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }

        console.log(c.fk_user.userName);
    });
});
```

**UPDATED from Pier-Luc Gendreau Answer's**

fb_db.model.js

```
module.exports = function (connection) {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var user_fb = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        location: String,
        fb_id: Number
    });

    return connection.model('User_FB', user_fb);;
}
```

feed_post.model.js

```
module.exports = function (connection) {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var feed_postSchema = new Schema({
        user_id:  { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User_Fb' },
        content: String,
        location: String,
        image: [{ type : String }]
    });

    return connection.model('Feed_Post', feed_postSchema);;
}
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),

mongoose = require('mongoose'),
conn_new_app = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/new_app'),
User_Fb = require('./app/models/fb_db.model')(conn_new_app),
Feed_Post = require('./app/models/feed_post.model')(conn_new_app);

app.get('/testget', function(req,res){
    Feed_Post.find().populate('user_id').exec(function(err, res) {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new connection in each and every model, so you end up with a bunch of different connection objects. Even though they are pointing to the same database, mongoose models don't know about other connections. You should instead create the connection object in your main app and then pass it around.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();
var conn_new_app = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/new_app');
var Feed_Post = require('./app/models/feed_post.model')(conn_new_app);

app.get('/testget', function(req,res){
  Feed_Post.findOne().populate('user_id').exec(function(err, c) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(c.fk_user.userName);
  });
});
```

Then modify your models so they are actually a function:

**feed_post.model.js**

```
module.exports = function (connection) {
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  var feed_postSchema = new Schema({
    user_id:  { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User_Fb' },
    content: String,
    location: String,
    image: [{ type : String }]
  });

  return connection.model('Feed_Post', feed_postSchema);;
}
```

Also, like Adrian mentions, you can use mongoose as a singleton. However, I do recommend using `createConnection` as you did because if you ever need a second connection, you won't have to refactor the connection code to your first database.

Comment: Hi, I understand what you meant by creating a new database connections. My other models are actually using another database's name which is why I am doing it that way. After following your advice/instructions, I am still receiving the same error. I have Updated my code in my question.

Comment: I just noticed you also have a typo. Your model name and ref don't match: `User_Fb` vs. `User_FB`

Comment: Oh! Such carelessness. Thanks Pier-Luc Gendreau! Got it working now, thanks to you!

Comment: Glad I could help, happens to the best of us! Also, it's good practice to use lowerCamelCase for variables rather than underscores. There are some style guides out there, most notably [standard](https://github.com/feross/standard) which has gathered quite a bit of steam lately.

Comment: I'll be taking a look at it now. Thanks again. :D

Answer (score 18):

This is all I had to do `Customer.findOne({}).populate({ path: 'created_by', model: User })` instead of this `Category.findOne({}).populate({'author'})`

Answer (score 10):

**IF YOU (really) USE MULTIPLE mongoDB CONNECTIONS**

---

I do realise that this is not the case for the OP, but if you genuinely use multiple connections you MUST provide the model when using .populate(), as mongoose will only "find" models on the same connection.
ie where:

```
var db1 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/gh3639');
var db2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/gh3639_2');
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  "name": String,
  "email": String
});

var customerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  "name" : { type: String },
  "email" : [ String ],
  "created_by" : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
});

var User = db1.model('users', userSchema);
var Customer = db2.model('customers', customerSchema);
```

**Correct:**

```
Customer.findOne({}).populate('created_by', 'name email', User)
```

or

```
Customer.findOne({}).populate({ path: 'created_by', model: User })
```

**Incorrect** (produces "schema hasn't been registered for model" error):

```
Customer.findOne({}).populate('created_by');
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are creating a different database connection for each model, which isolates the models from each other. Mongoose must assume this isolation, because they could exist on different databases or even database servers.

Try connecting once, and just calling `mongoose.model()` instead of `connection.model()` when defining your models. Mongoose is a singleton by default.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this issue because I haven't included the `ref model` into the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the field you want by using `select`

Example to get the email of the customer:

```
Customer.findOne({}).populate({ path: 'created_by', model: User, select: 'email' })
```

More Details in [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)